# Enviar un mensaje al usuario si no se selecciona la tabla antes de ejecutar el método (NetBeans, MSQL)

Tags: java, java-swing

creé un boton en NetBeans para eliminar registros de mi BD. La cosa está así: Necesitas seleccionar el registro en la tabla para que se ejecute el método de eliminación. Pero si no seleccionas la fila (registro) que quieres eliminar, el botón no hace nada (PERO INTERNAMENTE ME DA ERROR). Ahí es donde quiero poner un mensaje para decirle al usuario que 'Seleccione la fila (registro) que desea eliminar'. Pero no se como hacerlo, lo intente con if & else, Try, catch y tampoco me funciona.

Dejo unas imagenes para ver si me di a entender:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen de arriba presiono el boton pero no hace nada, es lógico, porque tengo que seleccionar la fila para que se ejecute el metodo.

Aca el mensaje de error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:737)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:480)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
at PKG.FORMULARIOS.VENTANA_ESTUDIANTE.ELIMINAR_REGISTRO(VENTANA_ESTUDIANTE.java:156)
at PKG.FORMULARIOS.VENTANA_ESTUDIANTE.BTN_ELIMINARActionPerformed(VENTANA_ESTUDIANTE.java:658)
at PKG.FORMULARIOS.VENTANA_ESTUDIANTE.access$800(VENTANA_ESTUDIANTE.java:15)
at PKG.FORMULARIOS.VENTANA_ESTUDIANTE$9.actionPerformed(VENTANA_ESTUDIANTE.java:489)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Aca dejo el codigo del método:

```
public void ELIMINAR_REGISTRO() {
    
    int FILA___SELECIONADA = JTABLE_ESTUDIANTE.getSelectedRow();

    try {
        String SQL = "DELETE FROM estudiantes WHERE ID_ESTUDIANTES=" + JTABLE_ESTUDIANTE.getValueAt(FILA___SELECIONADA, 0);
        Statement ST = CON.createStatement();
        int N = ST.executeUpdate(SQL);
        if (N >= 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "REGISTRO ELIMINADO");
        }
    } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR AL ELIMINAR REGISTRO" + e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el `if` que has intentado?

Comment: Si quieres usar un try catch, deberás capturar esta excepción: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, ya que es la que te salta al intentar leer el valor de una fila que no está en la lista de filas (-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo para solucionar tu problema puedes preguntar por el numero de la fila seleccionada si devuelve -1 muestras el mensaje informando al usuario que seleccione una fila del jtable:

```
 if (FILA___SELECIONADA == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes seleccionar un registro de la tabla", "No se eligio estudiante", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            
            return;
        }
```

Comment: GRACIAS AMIGO! se solucionó el problema

Comment: De nada amigo para esos estamos en esta comunidad para ayudarnos .

Comment: de cuasualidad tienes un proyecto que guarde varios documentos PDF, etc en mysql. Es decir, ingreso mi cédula y le doy a buscar, si no hay ningun documento guardado me aparezca un mensaje diciendo lo antes mencionado y una opción para agregar un nuevo archivo, y que es nuemro de archivos para ese estudiante sea ilimitado? Formulare una nueva pregunta para ver si alguien me puede ayudar.. :c